# Javascript Promises syntax differences?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am having little doubt with how javascript promises are used. I have learned it in a following basic format and it's understandable.

```
var dopromise = new Promise (function(resolve,reject){

let isclean=true;

if(isclean){
   resolve('done');
 }

else
{
    reject();
}
});
dopromise.then(function(done){
     console.log()
}).catch(function(){
 console.log()
)}
```

But I don't understand properly how promises work in below code scenario. Code looks much simpler without details. Have I missed something?

eg

```
navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
                 video: true;
 })
  .then(function(stream){
       alice.addStream(stream);
       return alice.createOffer();
  })
```

Comment: Is that legit in the then function? Stream = function(){...

Comment: Do you mean `stream => { ... }`?

Comment: FWIW, one thing about programming is that it's an exercise in detail-orientation. `Promise`, not `promise`. Consistent, readable indentation and formatting. I'm not sure what that syntax after `.then(` is meant to be, but it's not accepting a `Stream` (or `stream`) parameter... It's important to pay attention to details like this, particularly when asking for help.

Comment: @RobertMoskal - It's valid syntax, but it doesn't do what the OP likely wants it to do. It assigns a function to the variable `Stream` (which would want to be declared somewhere) and also passes that function into `then`. The `stream` in the function wouldn't be from the promise.

Comment: sorry folks , syntax error .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax is the same. Whatever is before `.then()` must produce a `Promise`. In your case, you created the `Promise` explicitly. In the case of

```
navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
    video: true;
})
```

`getUserMedia()` takes an object as a parameter and returns a `Promise`.

The rest is not legal JavaScript syntax as far as I know. You can either do

```
.then(function(stream){
   alice.addStream(stream);
   return alice.createOffer();
})
```

or with ES6

```
.then((stream) => {
   alice.addStream(stream);
   return alice.createOffer();
})
```

Comment: Thank you i have made some syntax error  and updated . can you please explain me in little more details how getUserMedia() produce promise .

Comment: @ambach66 I have no idea about the implementation of getUserMedia(). My answer here is based on how the return value is used. If you want to know more, I suggest reading the documentation. It is safe to treat this function as a black box. As long as you understand what kind of parameters to pass in and what the resulting return value is, you don't need the internal details.

Answer (score 4):

`getUserMedia` returns an already created `Promise`. In your first example you are manually creating a `Promise` in order to make something asynchronous.

Answer (score -2):

In very general / (computer) layman terms **promises** are functions which get executed "asynchrounsly" and therefore when they return any information, there should be some place where you can capture it.

The information returned is captured by a "callback function" called **then**.

This callback is invoked automatically (by the javascript engine) and "takes a function" as an argument, which is then called again automatically :)

So if I had a piece of code like this

```
somePromise().then(function() { console.log('2 - Promise returned 
something, executing in a separate thread') });

console.log('1 - This is executed in the main thread');
```

The output would technically be:

1 - This is executed in the main thread
2 - Promise returned something executing in a separate thread

Because the promise can take a long time to return depending on how much work it is doing and you don't want the main thread to wait that long.

Comment: The function that is passed to a `new Promise( )` is not executed asynchronously (see this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/s6n1kyq4/1/), the output is  `a b c` and not `a c b`), the resolving/rejecting of the Promise is async. A Promise is not executed in a separate thread, and if the code in the Promise is something long running/blocking, then all other code will still block, probably at another place but it will still block.

Comment: I was conveying a concept for the person to understand how "then" works on a promise. Yes, technically the code of the promise itself is not asynchronous.